# Switching/Upgrading from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, upgrade

A while ago I tried to get into programming but I hit a bit of a brick wall and after a while lost motivation. Back then I installed Visual Studio 2015 (the free version) and, not really knowing what i was doing, i ticked all of the "Workloads" which ended up installing something like 60+ GB of software.

Recently I have re-gained interest in coding and it's going far better. I went ahead and installed Visual Studio 2017 Community (for the sake of having the latest version of the software) but, knowing that i had 60+ GB of software installed on my PC i did not tick any of the "Workloads" in the VS 2017 Installer. I thought that it would just figure out that all of the stuff was already there.

Obviously it didn't because when I open VS 2017 and go to create a new project there are no templates there to choose from. I know i can just fire up the installer again, tell it to modify the install and install as many of the Workload-specific templates as I want but **here is my question:**

**If I, for example, go ahead and tell the VS 2017 installer it to install the required software for "Universal Windows Platform Development" (6.49 GB), will it realise that i already have an older version of that installed and update/upgrade it, or will it add *another* 6.49 GB *on top of what I already have*?**

Just to be clear:
I do realise that it will use up additional memory, even if it does only perform updates to what i already have installed. What I am trying to avoid is it installing a brand new  60 GB of software, ignoring the old one, and me having to go back and manually uninstall the outdated versions that VS 2015 left behind one-by-one.

Comment: *"will it realise that i already have an older version of that installed and update/upgrade it, or will it add another 6.49 GB on top of what I already have?"* Not sure. Many packages support side-by-side installation, by design, for multiple-targeting scenarios. (That is, some of us crazy programmers want to have all the versions installed at once on our machines so we can use whichever one we want at any given time.) So why take the risk? If you don't want the old stuff, re-run the VS 2015 installer and *remove* the unwanted packages (or the entire darn thing). Then reinstall VS 2017.

Comment: @CodyGray Can't believe I hadn't thought of re-running the old VS 2015 installer. And yeah, i can see the point in keeping multiple versions of the same software installed "just in case". Thanks for the fast answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you already installed the VS 2015 and try to install the VS 2017, it will **Not** update/upgrade the installed VS 2015. You can install and use Visual Studio 2017 alongside previous versions of Visual Studio, including Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, and Visual Studio 2012, we can know this information from [VS 2017 Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs)

If you do not want to use VS 2015 to clean up some spaces for VS 2017, you can try to uninstall it through the VS forcibly uninstall command like vs_community.exe /uninstall /force, for the detail information, please check: [Removing Visual Studio components left behind after an uninstall](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/)

If you do not want to completely uninstall the VS 2015, you can modify it and uncheck some components that you will not use recently, usually we are not install all components since it is a huge one and check those components that you required is better.

For the VS 2017, you can also try to modify it and only check the workloads that you need, you can check the workloads and confirm those components that it includes at the right side like the following screenshot, it is no need to select all workloads. 
[image]

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm gonna do, thanks for taking your time to answer! :)